# Set a default value for paper-input-container with custom logic

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to reproduce the Social Security Number example provided by the polymer demo [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-input). How can I set a default/initial value for paper-input-container with its ssn-input component inside? The running version is [here](https://jsbin.com/vazeduhepi/edit?html,output).

I tried to add the attribute value to both paper-input-container and ssn-input, but it does not display as initial default value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Element Test Case</title>
  <base href="//polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input-container.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input-error.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/demo/ssn-input.html">
</head>
<body>
   <paper-input-container always-float-label auto-validate attr-for-value="value">
          <label>Social Security Number</label>
          <ssn-input class="paper-input-input"></ssn-input>
          <paper-input-error>SSN invalid!</paper-input-error>
   </paper-input-container>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked the original implementation of the <[ssn-input](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/demo/ssn-input.html)>, and it seems to me that there is no code to split the provided value in its three substrings and provide it to the three paper-input. Instead when the user types something within the paper-inputs, each string becomes a _ssnX and a `computeValue` function links them together storing the result in the `value` property. Here the piece of code from [ssn-input.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/demo/ssn-input.html):

```
properties: {
  value: { notify: true, type: String },
  _ssn1: { type: String },
  _ssn2: { type: String },
  _ssn3: { type: String },

  validator: { type: String, value: 'ssn-validator' }
},
observers: [
  '_computeValue(_ssn1,_ssn2,_ssn3)'
],
_computeValue: function(ssn1, ssn2, ssn3) {
  this.value = ssn1.trim() + '-' + ssn2.trim() + '-' + ssn3.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssn-input` is the component that reads the content typed by the user and puts everything in the value property. Hence, the first thing is to initialise the value attribute of this element, as follows:

```
<paper-input-container always-float-label auto-validate>
    <label>Social Security Number</label>
    <ssn-input class="paper-input-input" value="102-12-1233"></ssn-input>
    <paper-input-error>SSN invalid!</paper-input-error>
</paper-input-container>
```

The attribute value initialises the relevant property in the ssn-input. `ssn-input` has three internal `input` element, which show and take the user input. Therefore, the initial value must be split on the "-" character. The best place to do it is in the `value` property observer. So, the modified ssn-input element code is the following:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'ssn-input',

  behaviors: [
    Polymer.IronValidatableBehavior
  ],

  properties: {
    value: { notify: true, type: String, observer: '_handleValueChanged' },
    _ssn1: { type: String },
    _ssn2: { type: String },
    _ssn3: { type: String },
    validator: { type: String, value: 'ssn-validator' }
  },

  _handleValueChanged: function(value) {
    var arr = value.split("-");
    this._ssn1 = arr[0];
    this._ssn2 = arr[1];
    this._ssn3 = arr[2];
  },

  observers: [
    '_computeValue(_ssn1,_ssn2,_ssn3)'
  ],

  _computeValue: function(ssn1, ssn2, ssn3) {
    this.value = ssn1.trim() + '-' + ssn2.trim() + '-' + ssn3.trim();
  }
});
```

Here, the jsbin [running example](https://jsbin.com/tasiwehoyo/1/edit?html,console,output).